# Pop to root in UISplitviewController inside of UITabBarController with second tap not working

Tags: ios, uikit

My configuration:

```
Tab1 -> UINavigationController
Tab2 -> UINavigationController
Tab3 -> UISplitViewController -> Master -> NavigationController
(Tab3 -> UISplitViewController -> Detail -> NavigationController)
```

On Tab1 and Tab2 ... I can push viewControllers and pop them to root by tapping twice the tab item.

My "phone" shows by default the Master by tap the third Tab. But by tapping the third TabButtonItem twice... it not popping the NavigationController to root.

Bug or feature ? ;-)

Comment: What is the cocoa tag for?